# Flutter/Dart ifdef to remove function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dart library which is imported into my flutter app.

The dart library has data and a number of debug functions/methods which I want to be completely excluded from my app, so that the code is both not called and does not take up any space.

I know I can use kReleaseMode and/or assert to only call functions in debug mode but not in production mode.

However I want to make sure that the debug functions do not take up any space in my app, ie. that the debug functions are not even defined or declared in production mode, exactly the same as if I went in and deleted the debug data and methods from my codebase.

In some languages I would do something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    void prodFunction()
    {
        // do something ...
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    static const debugData = [];

    void debugFunction()
    {
        // this method and the above List is not defined in production mode ...
    }
    #endif
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in Dart/Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be necessary to remove the debug code "manually", because the dart optimization (tree shaking) will take care of it: Functions that are never called if kReleasMode==true and variables that are only changed or accessed by those functions will simply not appear in the release-mode executable.

Of course, in the app importing the library you must not call the debugFunction (or only if kReleaseMode==false) if you want to profit from this optimization. But anyway, if it would be possible to remove the debugFunction using something like #ifdef, you couldn't call that function either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax like #ifdef in Dart as of now according to my knowledge, but if your goal is to remove a function from the release builds then you can use `assert` blocks.

The Dart compiler would remove all assert blocks from the code in the release/AOT snapshot.

```dart
void doSomething() {
  assert(() {
    // <- Your logic goes here ->
    return true;
  }());
}
```

The same pattern is used by the flutter framework internally here, is the method from the `framework.dart` file which checks if the initState method has returned the type of `Future` or not.

```dart
    assert(() {
      if (debugCheckForReturnedFuture is Future) {
        throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
          ErrorSummary('${state.runtimeType}.initState() returned a Future.'),
          ErrorDescription('State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.'),
          ErrorHint(
            'Rather than awaiting on asynchronous work directly inside of initState, '
            'call a separate method to do this work without awaiting it.',
          ),
        ]);
      }
      return true;
    }());
```